# Corrupted JSON HTTP response

Tags: c#, python, json, unicode

I am getting a HTTP request for a website and the content type is JSON. However, I am getting a nested JSON that is a unicode and is causing consistency problems.

Here is an example:

```
{"key1":"value",
"key2":"value",
"key3":{
      u'key31':u'value',
      u'key32':u'value'}}
```

This reminds me of python 2.7 troubles but I am not sure how to fix this JSON. I am using C# to parse it. Everything works correctly until I try to access key3.
The content should be a JSON object type but it is considered rather a value or a string.

Thanks for ya help. Is there a way to fix it if it is actually corrupted or am I parsing it wrongly?

Comment: So what is the question? How to fix this invalid json with regex or similar methods?

Comment: Mainly if this is actually corrupted and if yes, how to deal with that through C# leaving regex as the last option.

Comment: Yes it is corrupted. Best way is of course fix the server which sends this json, or ask people who are in charge to do that, if that's not your server.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that this json object is not complete / does not have the correct syntax. You're missing a closing '}' character.

How are you parsing your data? Try taking a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data).

Comment: Yeah sorry that was my fault to omit the bracket. The response I get have the correct notation. It is just a priori a  unicode problem. 
I am getting the content through :  req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>(); 
Then, I just send the content to another instance.

Answer (score 0):

your json object is not in valid formatted it should be like as folllows

```
   {  
   "key1":"value",
   "key2":"value",
   "key3":{  
      " u'key31'":"u'value'",
      "u'key32'":"u'value'"
   }
}
```

by any chance do you get this json from python dump? coz  Python's unicode literals are not valid JSON, and neither are single quotes

Comment: It is not my server so I do not really know.